# DIR list files with only one extension

Tags: windows-registry, cmd.exe, dir, directory-listing

The code below will list all files from the selected directory. How to make it list only files with one extension, like pdf?

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\4_content-list-pdf\command]
@="cmd /c dir \"%1\" /b /o:gn | clip"
```

Comment: Have you tried `\"%1\*.pdf\"`? or `\"%1\\*.pdf\"`?

Comment: The second string works like charm - thank you!

Comment: Great!. I will add an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to make it list only files with one extension, like pdf?

You can replace `\"%1\"` with `\"%1\\*.pdf\"` as follows:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\4_content-list-pdf\command]
@="cmd /c dir \"%1\\*.pdf\" /b /o:gn
```

Note:

> A small number of commands follow slightly different rules, `FINDSTR`, `REG` and `RUNAS` all use `\` as an escape character instead of `^`

Source [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.